# Writing Http request in Export Function MEANJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, meanjs

I used Yo MeanJs generator to get started. I am a beginner in MeanJs. It is looking complicated.

Actually My Meanjs App need to Fetch the data from http request Yet iam Querying LocalDB like following:

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
    Article.find().sort('-created').populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

I used Http request like below Code which raising error ... i can say that the Code is insane code  But pls suggest me something to get the Http Fruitful ... Thanks For the help in Advance !!!*

```
var http = require('http');

exports.list = function(req, res) {
    http.get('http://localhost:3030/articles').success(function(err, articles) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.json(articles);
        }
    });
};
```

which raising error for above:

```
TypeError: Object #<ClientRequest> has no method 'success'
    at exports.list (C:\Mean Workspace\prjts\marketplace-api-meanjs\app\controllers\articles.server.controller.js:76:49)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Mean Workspace\prjts\marketplace-api-meanjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:82:5)
    at next (C:\Mean Workspace\prjts\marketplace-api-meanjs\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:100:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gladly  I got an answer .... we need to Use  A Plugin called request .. to request in Modules... Good Plugin.

Refer the Following Links :- 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-json

```
 var request = require('request');

 exports.list = function(req, res) {


request.get(
    'http://localhost:3030/menus',

    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            //console.log(body);
          var obj = JSON.parse(body); //changing format to exact Json Obj
            res.json(obj);
        }
    }
);
```

};

For now it is throwing Json as Strings ...  Use request-json to get required Json ... Hooray   I Answered My Own Question For the first Time !!!